# How to send transaction from Polygon test network using web3.js?

Tags: web3js

I am trying to integrate transaction using Polygon test network by Web3.js. The same code is working fine for ethereum. But how to send transaction using Polygon test network? Do I need to modify any code ? I have created the polygon mumbai test network in Metamask.

```
    const initPayButton = () =>{
        
            sendTransaction({
                to: paymentAddress,
                value: toWei(amountEth, 'ether')
            }, (err, transactionId)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log("Payment Failed", err)
                    $('#status').html("Payment failed")
                }else{
                    console.log("Payment Successful", transactionId)
                    $('#status').html("Payment Successful")
                }
            }
            )
        }

        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first switch network of your wallet. So, before sending a transation, do this:

```js
try {
    await window.ethereum.request({
       method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain',
       params: [{ chainId: "0x13881" }],
    })
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

This will make MetaMask ask you to switch network to Polygon Testnet. After this, you can make your transaction.

Comment: Shall I use the above code in my code which I gave in the question?

Comment: Thanks it worked. But I need to know shall I have to change the ChainId: '0x13881' ? because I used '0x13881' and the code ran good. So I need to know shall I have to change the ChainId?

Comment: Sir, is the chain ID: '0x13881' is default ID for polygon test network?

Comment: Oh! I got it. 0x13881 is the hexadecimal conversion of the chainId. thanks man.

Comment: Yes, that is the hexadecimal chaind ID for Polygon testnet. You need to provide the chain ID of network you want to switch to